# I am stuck using a pivot function to get this result

Tags: sql-server

```
sDisplayName,sMonitorTypeDescription,sMonitorTypeName

BLACK   Test accessibility  Ping

BLACK   File Transfer Protocol (FTP Server) FTP

BLACK   TCP/IP Monitor  SSH

BLACK   NT Service Monitor  RPC Service

BLACK   WMI Monitor Disk C: Free Space below 2GB
```

I want this to look like:

```
sDisplayName,   Test accessibility, File Transfer Protocol (FTP Server),TCP/IP Monitor,NT Service Monitor,WMI Monitor
```

with data as:

```
BLACK Ping NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL

BLACK NULL FTP NULL NULL NULL NULL
```

and so on...

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Are those the only values possible for `sMonitorTypeDescription`?, or do you want your query to be dynamic?

Comment: Also, do you actually need one row for every original row?, so every row in your resultant query should have one actual value, and the rest should be `NULL`?, are you sure about that?

Comment: Can you post your schema and some sample data to SQLFiddle? Then we can help you write the query: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/about.html

Comment: Hi Lamak/Vince, I would first thank you for you time to look at this one. These are not the only values for sMonitorTypeDescription. I would like the query to be dynamic. I would like one row for every original row so every row in the query should have one actual value and rest null.

Comment: Vince,Here is my sample data: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bc872/1

Comment: Sorry, I would like my data to be output as comma separated and not each new row for every original row. So for Green 1 that has NT service monitor as A and B both should be output as A.B under NT monitor column (see sample data)